# React Universal pass data to component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I am brand new in react. I am trying to pass data from server to client via React universal rendering. But I am in now luck. Still I can render the html but I am not able to access data through this.props.data

Here is my code

// server.js

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match({
    routes: (<Router>{routes}</Router>),
    location: req.url
  },
    (err, redirect, renderProps) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      } else if (redirect) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirect.pathnam + redirect.search);
      } else if (renderProps.components.some(component => component === NotFoundPage)) {
        res.status(404);
      }

      let data = [
        {
          title: 'Godfather'
        },
        {
          title: 'Godfather 2'
        }
      ];

      data = JSON.stringify(data);
      const renderedApp = renderToString(
        <DataWrapper data={data}>
          <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
        </DataWrapper>
      );

      res.render('index.ejs', {
        renderedApp
      });
    });
});
```

// routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import HomePage from './components/routes/HomePage';
import MovieDetailsPage from './components/routes/MovieDetailsPage';
import NotFoundPage from './components/routes/NotFoundPage';
import App from './components/app';

export {
  NotFoundPage
}; 

export default (
  <Route path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="movie" component={MovieDetailsPage} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Route>
);
```

// client.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import DataWrapper from '../src/DataWrapper';

let data = [];

ReactDOM.render(
  <DataWrapper data={data}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} onUpdate={window.scrollTo(0, 0)}/>
  </DataWrapper>, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

// DataWrapper

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DataWrapper extends Component {
  getChildContext () {
    return {
      data: this.props.data
    };
  }

  render () {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

DataWrapper.childContextTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.object,
    React.PropTypes.array
  ]).isRequired
};

export default DataWrapper;
```

// HomePage.js where I want to access the data in this.props.data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction and explain if possible what I am doing wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're currently rendering the children in `DataWrapper`, but you're not passing in the props.

Not sure if this is the optimal way to do this, but here's how I get the props and state passed in

```
{this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
  state: this.state
})}
```

Comment: Hmm are you talking about putting this logic into HomePage.js.

Answer (score 0):

In this use case, I suggest using Redux instead of writing the custom data wrapper. Because 
Redux can make the single source of truth, all the components can refer to that, no matter which level it's in (parent or childen) and where is the page rendered (server or client). It can help you to make the architect clearer even it introduces more overhead.

Here's some pseudo code I used before:

// server.js

```
// configureStore will create a empty store here.
const store = configureStore();
// Then use store.setState or any middleware to prepopulate the store.
....
const jsx = (
  <ReduxProvider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>
  </ReduxProvider>
);
const html = '<!doctype html><html><head></head>
    <body>
      <script>
        window.REDUX_DATA = ${ JSON.stringify(store.getState()) }
      </script>
      <div id="root">${ReactDOM.renderToString(jsx)}</div>
    </body>
  </html>'
res.send(html)
```

//client.js

```
const render = App => {
  // configStore will create store in client side with initial state passed from server.
  const store = configStore(window.REDUX_DATA);
  return ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <App/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ReduxProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};
```

//HomePage.js

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        this.props.foo.value
      </div>
    )
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({foo: state.foo});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
}
```